A palindromic formula for simple convex polytopes
Let $P$ be a simple convex $d$-polytope (a $d$-dimensional convex polytope in which the number of edges incident to a vertex is $d$) and let $n_i$ be the number of $i$-faces of $P$. Is it true that the coefficients of $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^d n_i(t-1)^i$ are always palindromic?
For example a simple convex $3$-polytope with $n$ vertices necessarily has $3n/2$ edges and, since the Euler characteristic is $2$, $(n+4)/2$ faces.  Now $$(t-1)^3+ \frac{n+4}{2}(t-1)^2+\frac{3n}{2}(t-1)+n = t^3+\frac{n-2}{2}t^2+\frac{n-2}{2}t+1.$$
Similarly a simple convex $4$-polytope with $n$ vertices has $2n$ edges, and $n_2-n_3=n$ so
$$\sum_{i=0}^4 n_i(t-1)^i = t^4+(n_3-4)t^3+(n-2n_3+6)t^2+(2n-2n_2+3n_3-4)t+1$$ has palindromic coefficients.

This is true.  You can find a large amount of literature on the subject if you look up "h-vector" or "h-polynomial."

The fact that the h-vector is symmetric for simple polytopes is also an equivalent statement of the Dehn–Sommerville equations, so that can also be a starting point to searching the literature.

Relevant Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehn%E2%80%93Sommerville_equations
